# How do .rar utilities manage to decompress a hidden compressed file (which is actually binary content appended to another file)?

Tags: compression

After a puzzle in puzzles.SE which involved a hidden file appended to a gif, I have a question regarding appended .rar files.

By [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/705126/appending-one-file-to-the-end-of-another) I understand why I can add a .rar file content at the end of any known image format, as long as such format declares their data length in some way that any compliant reader would load only the required amount of bytes, and not read until end of file.

I can generate such file like this:

```
$ cat myimg.jpg myhidden.rar > myimg.jpg
```

Which works for any of the mentioned formats and will happily open as a regular image in the image viewer.

What surprised me is that I can actually open the hidden file! This is:

```
$ sudo apt-get install unrar
$ unrar e myimg.jpg
```

and will extract the files inside the contents of myhidden.rar

And my question is: How is that possible? My first thought in the matter would be that when I try to open my file, the .rar header is not found at the top (instead, a strange format the rar... parser, should not recognize), but somehow the utility manages to find the actual rar file and open it. I noticed this works both in Ubuntu and in Windows with WinRAR.

What am I missing? Does this work with other formats as well? (concretely: .zip, .7z, .tar.gz).

Comment: I'm not sure if the OP's imagination is founded on anything "I imagine that it's not required for RARs to be at an offset of zero within a given file, and that archive applications will look for the [RAR's header](http://www.forensicswiki.org/wiki/RAR)". I briefly scanned through that forensicswiki page, but didn't glean that fact, although it might be seen with a more technical eye than mine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This also works with .zip

Basically, the start of a "ZIP file" is a known header (which starts with "PK").

A program which knows how to handle ZIP files can search any file for a known header, and then treat that header and all later bytes like a ZIP file.

For instance, Info-Zip contains executable files named "unzipsfx.exe".  There are various versions of the file (e.g. version 5.12 for DOS, version 5.12 for OS/2, version 5.12 for Win32).  You can create a "self-extracting zip file", which is an executable file that is able to extract itself, by making a new file that starts with a version of this "unzipsfx.exe" and then adding a ZIP file to the end of it.  So, if I added the OS/2 variation (with "`copy/b unzipsfx.exe+myfile.zip myfile.exe`") then I could easily extract it with OS/2.  Although I couldn't run the file (to effectively extract the compressed data) from a computer running MS-DOS (because MS-DOS doesn't run OS/2 software), I could still use PKUNZIP for MS-DOS.

Such self-extracting files are common enough that any popular uncompressing software ought to be able to handle such variations of the files.  They simply look for the known header.  I distinctly remember some software (I forget offhand which software) that would complain, by showing a warning message, about the extra bytes at the beginning of the file.  However, it would still work just fine.

Edit, to add this clarification of unrar's behavior in the sample scenario: unrar isn't processing the JPG and ignoring the JPG because it fully understands the structure of what a JPG file is like.  It is simply ignoring the uninteresting bytes (which happen to be a JPG file) until it finds what it wants: bytes that start to look like a "RAR" archive.  Most .rar files have a RAR archive starting at the first byte, but this isn't an absolute requirement of a RAR archive.  Since the official RAR software supports creating self-extracting files (for various operating systems), I'm sure that RAR also supports capabilities similar to how ZIP files are handled.

Comment: But this capability would not work if the same sequence of magic bytes (bytes of interest for the rar parser) appeared in the content of the starting file, or would it work somehow?

Comment: That is a potential issue.  I believe common self-extracting executable files simply don't have matching headers, because they are carefully crafted (and trashed if they cause problems).  It may also be that the software tends to be more intelligent...  The ZIP file header may be more than just the "PK" that I mentioned above.  Software could look for longer headers, and even if a false positive ("corrupted partial archive") is found, it could look later in the file.  I'm not actually certain whether many programs actually does that or not, although it is certainly theoretically possible to do